# Overlaying Images on top of each other so they both show

Tags: effects, animation, animation-rendering, blender, transitions

I would like to show an animation of an transparent image being overlaid on top of another image, But have both images show on the screen at the same time.
The first image would be on the screen then the second image would come from the top of the screen and fit like a hand and a glove on top of the existing image.

At the moment the top image just covers up the bottom image, is there a way to overlay the top image on the bottom image so the to graph is transparent and they seamlessly fit together? PS: the image isn't to scale but hopefully you get the idea.

Image 1 is already on screen
[image: Image1]

Image 2 comes down from top and is transparent and overlays on top of image 1
[image: Image2]

Image 3 example of image 2 coming down from top of screen and overlaying on top of image 1
[image]

PS: I'm using kdenlive and using Ubuntu,  However I can use any opensource app and I'm willing to learn it.

Is this the right group for this question?  If not which one should I post it to?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the image isn't actually transparent.  I am not familiar with kdenlive, but any decent NLE should allow for transparent layers.  As long as the images actually have transparent backgrounds, it should just work to animate one layer coming in on the other.  I would try using GIMP to make sure to remove everything but the line itself from the second image and place the line in a transparency supporting image format (such as 32 bit TGA), then try again.  If it still doesn't work, maybe kdenlive doesn't work and you could try one of the other editors on the [open-source video editors question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/2274/good-open-source-video-editors).